# Only displaying part of a returned MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to filter out results of a MySQL query. I am pulling data from a Wordpress database. Specifically, I am trying to pull just the user role.

In Wordpress, the returned value is something like this:

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

All I want to see returned is the "administrator", "author", "subscriber", etc, and not all the other information.

From my understanding (I am very much a beginner however), I can't use a substr() because the length of characters is different, and the information before the role varies as well.

Is there anyway to filter out all the other information and just return "administrator" in the MySQL query directly?

Here is my current query (I am also pulling names, email address, passwords, etc from another table):

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_email, wp_users.user_pass, wp_users.display_name, wp_usermeta.user_id, wp_usermeta.meta_value
FROM wp_users 
JOIN wp_usermeta 
ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%admin%') 
OR (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%author%') 
OR (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%')
```

Comment: `SELECT wp_users.display_name  FROM wp_users JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id WHERE (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%admin%') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%author%') OR (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%')`

Comment: Why do people insist on placing large blocks of code in comments? They're all but unreadable.

Comment: So where i have to put?

Comment: apologies for the block of code, and thanks for the fix. This was my first post, will keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is PHP serialized (serialized via `serialize()` PHP function).

At first you need it deserialize:

```
$dbValue = 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}';
$arr = unserialize($dbValue)

print_r($arr);
```

Which outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["administrator"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

If you are sure, that the role/user group will be always first, you can get it like.

```
$role = array_keys($arr)[0];
```

Did I solve your problem?

Comment: I think this sets me in the right direction. I was looking at it backwards, which explains why I couldn't find an answer. I'll research PHP serialization a bit more, but so far its looking right.

Answer (score 1):

That’s PHP’s [serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data format, so you can simply use [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get it parsed back into a usable data structure.

(And if you are not totally sure what that data structure contains, then use `var_dump` to make a debug output of it.)